# Add a command flag based on a condition in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a command written like below in Ansible,

```yaml
- set_fact:
    user_arg: true
    some_arg: "--with some-ver=1.0.0 if {{ user_arg is defined else '' }}"
    path: "path/to/file"
- command: "some-command {{ some_arg }} {{ path }}"
```

Please note, I am adding argument name (`--with`) and its value (`some-var=1.0.0`) if `user` argument is defined.

I want to use `args` and switch it to look something like

```yaml
- set_fact:
    user_arg: true
    some_arg: "--with some-ver=1.0.0 if {{ user_arg is defined else '' }}"
    path: "path/to/file"
- command: "some-command {{ path }}"
  args:
    some_arg: "{{ some_arg }}"
```

But this adds `some_arg` with empty value, I do not want it to be added at all if `user_arg` is undefined. Could any one help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`default` filter with the `omit` variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#omitting-parameters) for that.

This will set the argument `some_arg` if `user_arg` is defined, otherwise, no argument at all will be sent to the command.

```yaml
- command: "some-command {{ path }}"
  vars:
    path: "path/to/file"
  args:
    some_arg: "{{ user_arg|default(omit) if user_arg is not defined else '--with some-ver=1.0.0' }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `set_fact` to set a variable and use it in the same `set_fact`. 
 You have to break them up:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    user_arg: true
    path: "path/to/file"

- set_fact:
    some_arg: "{% if user_arg is defined %}--with some-ver=1.0.0{% endif %}"
```

Now, what I think you *actually* want is to set `some_arg` if `user_arg` is set and `true`.  If so...

```yaml
- set_fact:
    some_arg: "{% if user_arg is defined and user_arg %}--with some-ver=1.0.0{% endif %}"
```

Comment: Interesting how we understood the question differently

Comment: thanks Jack, but I want exactly @β.εηοιτ.βε has described in his answer, sorry for not being clear.